# How does enterprise distribution of iOS apps restrict distribution outside of one company?

Tags: iphone, distribution, enterprise

How does Apple's enterprise distribution system prevent a person from downloading an app targeted at an enterprise that they do not belong to?

Comment: Enterprise application will need provisioning profile with which they are signed. And I think it is not available with application.Only that enterprise can provide it.

Comment: i agree with you, but suppose enterprise provide this  provisioning profile to their one of its customer "which is not an employee of the enterprise" then?? is customer will allow to download or how apple will know that this person is not a enterprise employee?

Comment: In that case I don't think apple will have any problem. What issue apple will have by this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the only restriction for Enterprise apps is the provisioning profile.  Apple does not know or restrict Enterprise apps based on device.

If you want to restrict an app to members of a company, then you may need to take additional steps.