# Distributing iOS application using Enterprise License

Tags: ios, enterprise, ios-enterprise

I am working on building an application which needs to be distributed to users of different business organization.

So my question is Can I enroll for a iOS Enterprise Program and distribute application to these business users?

Comment: You will risk breaking the agreement with Apple when you  distribute apps signed with enterprise certificate to anyone outside your organisation. Ideally your client should provide you with his enterprise certificate. [Read more..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523501/how-does-apple-catch-enterprise-apps-being-distributed-out-side-of-the-corporati)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood from enterprise program, you can distribute applications only to employees of the company you enroll. So if the companies are different you can't, but if they are under the same umbrella you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

No, the enterprise Program only allows distribution among employees of the company.
As clearly state on the [iOs Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) website.

> **Distribute In-house Apps**
>
> Distribute proprietary, in-house iOS apps to your employees. You can also securely host and wirelessly distribute or update in-house
>   apps to employees, keeping them current anywhere, anytime.

But is will work, with the enterprise account you can install the application without register the UDID. But be aware that allow the app to be installed by none employees is against the license, which if Apple found out could they could retract to the license.

Comment: Do you know it is possible getting crash logs from app, distributed with Enterprise License to external company? They have their "own" bundle ID. Or we need to use a 3rd party crash reporting tool? Because Apple seems not sending us the reports in a usual "App Store" / own bundle ID way.