# Developing iOS app for customers corporate appstore

Tags: ios, ios-enterprise

This is my scenario.

I work for Company-A and have developed and released an app in Apple AppStore. My company is enrolled in [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/). This allows me to host the app in our corporate appstore so that QA spread across the globe can download and test it.

Now, CustomerCompany-1 and CustomerCompany-2 are 2 of my customers who want some specialized functionality in the app that is applicable only to their companies. While I can develop the custom apps, I'm not sure how I can deliver apps to these customers so that they can host them in their corporate app stores.

Do they are also need to be part of iOS Developer Enterprise Program? Should I make separate builds for them in order to achieve this?

I will accept "NOT POSSIBLE" as an answer but need some insights to support the answer.

EDIT:

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493345/distributing-ios-application-using-enterprise-license) and the comment by Amar is very interesting to me. IF the customers give me their enterprise certificate, can I build the app using that certificate so that they can host on their own app store. This would perfectly work for me, since I will be using customers certificate and hence we need not have physical control over the server.

Comment: You need to add more detail. For example, does the app have login functionality? If so, you might be able to separate out features based on logins vis-a-vis the company they belong to.

Comment: @JimBeam Let's assume that we cannot differentiate the functionalities that should be supported based on logins. I definitely need to develop a custom app that needs to be hosted on customers corporate appstore. Is that possible is my question.

Comment: why dont you just treat them as two different apps, bind them with different bundle ID and host them on different Server?

Comment: @Geet Sounds interesting!! You mean to say I should host the app on my server so that customer can use them? Unfortunately, customer want to host the app on their corporate appstore only. It is confusing me as to how I can build an app that the customer can host on their appstore?

Comment: I assume by "Customers App store" u mean to  say the customer want to host it on thier Secure Server you mean, what I would guess is create two apps, with different bundle ids, and while you create the iPA just mention the different Link of thier hosting server

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the customer companies are not a legally owned entity of your company, each customer company must have their own enterprise license. You can only distribute enterprise apps to employees, contractors or supervised customers of the licensed enterprise.

You do not need specific builds for them (unless you want to for feature reasons), but they must be distributed using their own enterprise license.

> “Internal Use Applications developed under this Agreement may be
>   deployed on Deployment Devices in two ways: (1) deployment for
>   internal use by Employees, and (2) deployment for use by Customers
>   either on Your physical premises or under the direct supervision and
>   physical control of Your Employees in other locations, subject to
>   Apple’s right to review and approve such deployment as set forth
>   herein.”
>
> (f) Allow Your Customers to use Your Internal Use Applications, but
>   only (i) on Your physical premises, or (ii) in other locations,
>   provided all such use is under the direct supervision and physical
>   control of Your Employees (e.g., a sales presentation to a Customer).
>
> Except as set forth in Section 2.1(f) [The section quoted above], You
>   may not use, distribute or otherwise make Your Internal Use
>   Applications available to Your Customers or to any third parties in
>   any way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But it clearly states that I should have direct supervision and physical control of the location where the app is hosted. But this may not be possible in my case. I hand over the app to customer and he hosts it in their app store over which my company will not have any control? Is such a thing possible? Based on what I read here, it looks NO.

Comment: Have edited the question based on discussion from another SO question. Simply put, is it possible to build an app specifically for that customer IF they provide me with their enterprise certificate?